# value of one column based on value of another column in R

Tags: r

I have to find value minimum value in one column and based on that value I have to find the value corresponding in another column.

my data set is K and i have column name as X, Y:

```
> K
   X  Y
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
5 10 11
```

The columns have these values and i find the minimum value of column Y using

```
apply(K[c(2)],2,min) # this gives me 3.
```

now i have to relate it to column X which i am finding difficult.

I am totally new to R and i am still learning. Also i don't know any other libraries other than, `library(readr)`.

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you want to do with `X`?

Comment: I want the code to return 
 x value as 2 and Y value as 3.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to get the entry in `X` which is placed in the same row as the minimum of `Y`, you can try:

```
# create example data.frame:
K <- data.frame(X = seq(2, 10, 2), Y = seq(3, 11, 2))

# find index of minimum entry in column Y:
idx <- match(min(K$Y), K$Y) # gives you the first entry of the minimum
idx2 <- which(min(K$Y) %in% K$Y) # gives you all indices of the minimum

# output the corresponding element (or elements) in column X:
K$X[idx]
K$X[idx2]
```

Regarding the second part of your question, Datacamp has a free introductory course to R covering the very basics.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `apply`. If you know there is only one value of Y that is the lowest or you need the first record of the lowest Y, you can use `which.min`. Otherwise use `min` as this is more robust. In your example it doesn't matter, but test both methods on your full data.frame to see if there is a difference.

```
K[K$Y == min(K$Y), ]
  X Y
1 2 3

K[which.min(K$Y), ]
  X Y
1 2 3
```

Comment: ohk. Thankx. Btw what does writing before comma indicates.
its a row operation right? so does it return the entire row corresponding to minimum value of Y?
what if i just want for another certain coloumn?

Comment: Please help me understand the concept of comma.

K[K$Y ==  , min(K$Y) ]

i wrote like this and it threw up an error saying unexpected ','

i would be thankful to you.

Comment: @PrashantKumar, `K[ , ]`, everything before the comma is indeed a row operation, everything after the comma is for selecting columns. So K[K$Y == 3, ] will return all the rows and all the columns where K$Y == 3. In your code, the comma should be after min(...), exactly as in my first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what you mean by "relate". Let's say you want to find all rows where X is less than the minimum of row Y:

```
 K[K$X<min(K$Y),]
```

Will result in:

```
  X Y
1 1 2
```

The command is a subset command, it asks to give all the columns of any row where X is smaller than the minimum of the entire column of Y.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and there's a "tidier" way to do this with a mutate and filter:

```
    K %>% mutate(minY=min(Y)) %>% filter(Y=minY).
```

This can be used with group_by as well if you need the minimum record for each group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to explore other libraries (which eventually you will...), `data.table` is the one worth exploring.
with `data.table` -

```
k <- data.table(
  X = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
  Y = c(3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
)
```

will give you -

```
Description:data.table [5 × 2]
X         Y
<dbl>   <dbl>
2          3            
4          5            
6          7            
8          9            
10         11           
5 rows
```

Now to find minimum of Y and corresponding X value, you just need this -

`k[, .(min_Y = min(Y), corr_X = X[which.min(Y)])]`

which will give you -

```
Description:data.table [1 × 2]
min_Y corr_X
<dbl> <dbl>
  3     2
```